# Stored Procedure Wizards in IBM Data studio 2.2.1.0

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

I've recently downloaded DB2 Express C( VERSION 9.7) and IBM Data Studio version 2.2.1.0. I'm quite new to using data studio, and did have a play with it about a year ago. Now that I've got the latest, I was trying to create a simple stored procedure, I did as shown in the help, I remember from playing with data studio a year ago that when the stored procedure wizard launched, it took me through 4 steps,

Step 1 - I could set the name, and language, even a specific name

Step 2 - I could write the code, or use some built in help to give me some basic structure to using sql including setting sqlstate, and sqlerror codes...

Step 3 and Step 4 let me confirm various choices.

In the current version (2.2.1.0) I don't seem to get any of these rather nice guides that help a novice figure out how to write basic SQL statements. Is there any way to enable this?
I found it extremely useful and am now struggling without the helpful step by step wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to switch to the Data perspective. Then click File -> New -> Stored Procedure. It will open the wizard.

Another way is to open the Data Project Explorer view. Right click and Create a new Data Development Project. Open/expand the project to see the Stored Procedures folder. Right click the Stored Procedures folder and select New. This will open the wizard. You can do it this way in other Perspectives besides the Data perspective.